# In Clean Architecture, must Repository is Android or Kotlin module?

Tags: android, repository, clean-architecture

In Clean Architecture, a Repository contains Remote (Retrofit) and Local (Room) data source. I see Remote is pure Kotlin module. However because Room need to access Android Context, thus Local is Android module.

So, must Repository is Android module because of Local module? And if yes, do you know any abstraction to avoid Context in Local module and make that module becomes pure Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

The distinction isn't between programming language. The deciding factor is whether it relies on any components from Android, such as Context, to operate.

I have a module written in kotlin that is a `java-library`. This library contains my "domain" logic and does not contain any Android components.

In your case, because you're using Room, yes this module will need to be a `com.android.library` module.

I don't think there is a way round this. You could split your module into two obviously: one for Retrofit (`data-api`) and one for `Room` (`data-local`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I know, because children module is Android (`local`), this container module (`repository`) must be Android module too. It seems no way to abstract it.

Comment: I believe you are correct. You can use a `java-library` in a `com.android.library` module but not that other way around

Answer (score 1):

Here's [link](https://github.com/mkw8263/AndroidCleanArchitectureDemo)
It's good to see the open source on the link above.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).